# Fragments : unable to start activity Component Info

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm really confused on what I've done with my code. 
It's just a simple app using Fragments but I get below error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
```

This is my MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Activity-main XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    tools:context="com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind.MainActivity">
```

I just wanted a Fragment inside my activity main, what's wrong with my code?

This is the Fragment class i use :

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {}

    String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Sunny - 31/20",
            "Tomorrow - Sunny  - 42,30",
            "Wednesday - Rainy - 20,15",
            "Thursday - FINIMONDO - 35,20"
    };
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,list);
        ListView lw = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        lw.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

And its XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind.MainActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Did you try add any view which already has a parent? The code you share I did the same thing before and its working fine for me. Can you share more code?

Comment: How about using replace() instead of add()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the code as following in your `onCreateView` method

```
View  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

You missed to add `false`. Thanks.

Comment: That was it! Stupid error, really thanks! Love this community

Comment: Welcome. Happy codding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment()).commit() instead of  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment()).commit()

Comment: I get this message : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()

Comment: did you try replace instead of add?

Comment: I did. that is the messagge i get!

Comment: May be you can try replacing the frame layout inside the fragment xml with a Relative or Linear Layout

Comment: I tried, but now the screen is blank! I cannot visualize my ListView. 
Now it gives me this error : "The surrounding layout (@layout/activity_main) did not actually include this layout. What can I do?